# ansible get tag_Name and set hostname over multiple hosts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, jinja2

```
- hosts: ALL
gather_facts: true
remote_user:test
vars:
  Env: "{{ env }}"
tasks:
  - ec2_remote_facts:
    region: us-east-1
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    filters:
     "tag:Env": "{{ env }}"
    register: instance_facts
  - name: group_hosts
    add_host: hostname={{ item }} groups=dev
    with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances|map(attribute="private_ip_address)|list }}"
  - name: "loop over hosts for hostnames"
    hostname:
     name: {{ item }}
     with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances|map(attribute=' ')|list }}"
```

My intention in this playbook is  to get the tag_Name and set the same as hostname in the instances. I was trying different things, but got stuck while using the attribute for tag in the "loop over hosts for hostames" task. How do I mention the Tag = "Name" to save it as hostname as it would be a nested attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should split your playbook into two plays:

1. generate in-memory inventory
2. run tasks on hosts

Here's an example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ec2_remote_facts:
        region: us-east-1
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        filters:
          "tag:Env": "{{ env }}"
        register: instance_facts
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.tags.Name }}"
        ansible_host: "{{ item.private_ip_address }}"
        group: dev
      with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances }}"

- hosts: dev
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - hostname:
        name: {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go about this is set it in the userdata.

In Linux:

```
pip install awscli
ID=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
REGION=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed -e "s/.$//")
NAME=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$ID" --region $REGION --output=text | grep Name | awk '{ print $3 }')
#set the hostname according your distro
```

Comment: userdata only works during the launch of the instances. Is'nt that the understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

@Konstantin Suvorov thanks that is great example.
i will add pause after '- add_host:' in order for second part to complete:

```
- name: Let's wait for SSH to come up. Usually that takes ~10 seconds
      local_action: wait_for
        host={{ item.private_ip }}
        port=22
        state=started
      with_items: '{{ instance_facts.instances }}'
```